# How to sum multiple columns with different grouping criteria

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sum, grouping

Currenly i am doing a project where i required to generate report which extracted from table.
the table as per below

CURRENCY_A  AMOUNT_A    CURRENCY_B  AMOUNT_B    CURRENCY_C  AMOUNT_C

My expectations is the grand total sum of (AMOUNT_A+AMOUNT_B+AMOUNT_C) group by the currency
USD :
EURO    :
POUNDS  :

Is it possible to perform this output in oracle alone?

Comment: it'll be easier if you normalize your table

Comment: thanks, but the problem is i cant change the table structure already

Comment: @user2720648 Why have you deleted that sample of data you posted? Moreover, it would've been even better if you'd provided  a desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT currency, SUM(total1) AS total FROM
(
SELECT currency_a AS currency, SUM(a_amount)  AS total1 FROM table1
GROUP BY currency_a
UNION ALL
SELECT currency_b, SUM(b_amount) AS total2 FROM table1
GROUP BY currency_b
UNION ALL
SELECT currency_c, SUM(c_amount) AS total2 FROM table1
GROUP BY currency_c
) T
GROUP BY currency
```